# ECMAScript 6 and potential related flags

Tags: discussion, code-golf, rules

I know that compiler flags (such as `-D` for C/C++) are counted towards byte count, but what about interpreter flags? How would those affect byte count?

Given that the question is specifically about ECMAScript 6, this is more specifically asking if I would have to add 9 to my score for `--harmony` added to the command `node --harmony` to use ECMAScript 6?

Comment: Just run it in Firefox's console. :P

Comment: @m.buettner It was also intended to address using Node+ES6, which would be a whole lot more suitable for golfing than with Node+ES5 for a variety of reasons (least of which include fewer uses of `function` and `prototype`).

Comment: Note that you might be able to abbreviate `--harmony` to `--h` or `--ha`

Comment: @professorfish No, but it doesn't count, anyways, because it's selecting a language version, not defining something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would say no. ECMAScript 6 is sufficiently different from its previous versions that I would consider it a new language.

(By the same logic, you could technically say that using C++11 would require a +10 character count because of the `-std=c++11` compilation flag, and then you could include all sorts of goodies like the object file names and whatnot, which would increase each C++ submission's length by around 50.)

Answer (score 0):

I would not count flags that choose versions of a language. So, `gcc -std=c99` and `perl -M5.010` add zero to the score. Likewise, `python2.7` (as my computer calls it) adds zero to the score. I also would not count flags like `-f` in `awk -f program.awk`, as `-f` only specifies which file to run.

I do count other flags. I wrote [a sed program in 300 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27027/4065). I posted it as 299 characters, but changed the count to 299+1 because I used `sed -r`. After golfing this flag, `sed -rf program.sed` is 1 more character than `sed -f progrma.sed`.

Some flags might *decrease* the character count (or byte count) of a program. I like to avoid flags: I would not type `cc -DW=while`, I would put `#define W while` (15 characters) in my program. I would not type `perl -n`, I would put the shebang `#!perl -n` (9 characters) on [the first line](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28600/4065). By doing this, I increase my score and fail at golf.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, -1 for the last. Why wouldn't you use `-Dw=while` and count it towards the character count if that makes your code shorter? Also, shebangs are generally not counted in [tag:code-golf]. You would only count `-n` towards the character count.