# How to count bytes FAQ

Tags: discussion, faq, code-golf, answers, scoring

We've got a lot of questions asking how to count the bytes in different situations.  This question is here to put them all in one spot.

## General questions

[<s>How to count "interactive" answers and flags</s>](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions) (revised to: [Let's solve the flag problem once and for all](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/52210))
[How to count REPLs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7842/when-is-code-that-requires-a-repl-acceptable)
[How to count multiple files](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/counting-bytes-for-multi-file-programs)
[How to count lambdas](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/how-do-we-calculate-the-length-of-lambda)
[How to count whitespace](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6886/how-are-line-breaks-and-formatting-counted-for-code-golf-challenges/6893#6893)
[How to count shebangs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5635/should-the-lang-racket-line-be-included-in-code-golfs/5637#5637)
[How to count "expanded text"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7121/how-to-count-bytes-in-macro-heavy-languages-e-g-common-lisp)
[How to count encodings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5878/what-character-encodings-may-a-submission-use)
[How to count language-switch flags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/ecmascript-6-and-potential-related-flags)

## Language/feature-specific questions

[7](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10809/62131)
[Algodoo](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10761/45941)
[APL](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9428/20469)
[Assembly](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12339/46271)
[Box 256](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9012/how-to-score-box-256-answers)
[Desmos.com](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/does-desmos-com-count-as-a-programming-language/7077#7077)
[Folders](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/how-to-count-programs-in-folders)
[LabView](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7502/programming-in-labview-how-to-measure-program-size/7628#7628)
[Lego WeDo](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/how-to-score-the-lego-wedo-programming-language)
[Minecraft](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/programming-in-minecraft-redstone-how-to-measure-program-size)
[PHP GET](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7575/scoring-php-get-parameters)
[PHP -r/-R/-F](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/running-php-with-r-instead-of-code-tags)
[Piet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10991/31716)
[Scratch](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/673/golfing-in-scratch)
[TI-Basic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/how-to-score-ti-basic/4764#4764)
[VBA immediate Window](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12476/vba-immediate-window-byte-count)
[VB.NET auto-includes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7496/how-to-compile-score-answers-in-net-languages-specifically-vb-net)
[Vim](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8995/how-should-vim-answers-be-scored)
[Vitsy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8494/do-i-need-to-count-the-newline-for-vitsy-methods)

---

[Return to FAQ index](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/community-faq-for-programming-puzzles-code-golf)

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this is incredibly helpful and will be a great place to point new users to.

Comment: @AlexA. For some reason, there is no FAQ section on the right side.

Comment: PHP GET is actually a standard accepted input method: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7591/14732 (current score: +14 -5). Also, POST would fall in the same category as GET.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Ok?  This question isn't about what is/isn't allowed, but rather how we count the bytes.  The PHP GET question about is specifically how we count the bytes with PHP GETs.

Comment: @NathanMerrill The accepted answer in the PHP GET link, in short, says that PHP GET isn't an accepted input method and that the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the question is still valid, but the answer is out of date.  I'd post a comment (or a new answer).

Comment: @NathanMerrill That's where I was trying to get, The answer is old and (now) is wrong as well.

Comment: How do you count poyglots for languages that normally use different encodings?

Comment: @ГригорийПерельман: You find a sequence of bytes that works in all the programs, and then take the number of bytes. The various languages may well interpret each interpret this sequence as a different sequence of characters (so typically you'd present one of the programs as the "main" one and then say what the other languages see in your explanation).

Comment: Surprisingly, there is no answer linked from this FAQ for the most basic case: when a single piece of code is posted as codegolf answer. Most answers and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info talk about byte size, but those answers are posted as Unicode strings, without an explicit encoding, so there is no obvious an unambiguous way to determine the byte size. Are there any relevant guidelines here?

Comment: "How to count encodings" would be the general guideline for that.