# VBA Immediate window Byte count

Tags: discussion, tips

What are the rules for counting bytes in the immediate window? I have found very little in the way of VBA docuimentation to try and help with this, because is seems to be a relatively uncommon golfing language. *For clarity, I'm not sure how the rules would be applied in a few test cases below, and would like an explanation of how to count the bytes for these VBA specific examples*

If I type into the immediate window, several things are returned, **I want to know the byte count of what is returned** (prompted by [my answer to this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121167/68602)). Here's some specific cases I'm not sure about:

```
?;
```

When I enter this, I am put on a new line. Pressing <kbd>↓</kbd> down arrow does nothing, so I assume no bytes are below the cursor. I notice that a space is added after the `;`, so I'm guessing the byte count is 1 for the space + 1 for the newline? Or is it customary to not count the extra space?

Meanwhile

```
?a
```

That evaluates the constant a, undefined at this point. When entered, the cursor is put 2 lines below the input, rather than immediately below as before. Also, a space is put after the a, and on the intermediate line. So that suggests 2 newlines and 2 spaces = 4 byte output. Also, unlike before, pressing <kbd>↓</kbd> does do something, it takes me onto the next line. So maybe 3 newlines?

Finally

```
?,
```

I have no idea what's going on there, does it count as a tab or a load of spaces? Maybe I'm mixing up newlines and spaces, I'm not sure.

Comment: What are you trying to count and why? Normally we care about counting the bytes in your code, for scoring purposes, so I can't understand why you're worried about how many bytes of output you're getting.

Comment: @PeterTaylor sometimes output size matters: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121056/output-with-the-same-length-as-the-code

Answer (score 2):

`?;` doesn't add a space to the end of the line. When you select all text in the immediate window, it visualises the line-break by adding a bit of space to the end, but it isn't an actual space. Try moving the caret there. The command `?;` means `PRINT (nothing) and suppress tabs and newlines`. Newlines are added automatically by VBA to print statements, except when suppressed with `;`. This statement therefore has an output of 0 bytes.

`?,` means `PRINT (nothing), then TAB and print (nothing again)`. Since newlines are not suppressed, that is also added. In my command window, it seems to add 14 spaces instead of a single tab. I find it hard to score this... I'd go for 2 bytes: tab and newline.

`?a` says `Print the undefined var a (nothing)` and is again followed by a newline. Output 1 byte.

The cursor is moved to either 1 or 2 lines below the statement (depending on newlines being allowed or suppressed) simply to allow you to type the next statement and should not be considered as output.

Comment: I'm not convineced on the first one, purely because the 'space' can be selected, pressing ctrl+a and pasting into a [byte counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) gives 3 not 2

Comment: Yes, [it's 3 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=utf-16&t=%27%u05D0%u05D1%u05D2%u05D3%u05D4%u05D5%u05D6%u05D7%u05D8%u05D9%u05DB%u05DA%u05DC%u05DE%u05DD%u05E0%u05DF%u05E1%u05E2%u05E4%u05E3%u05E6%u05E5%u05E7%u05E8%u05E9%u05EA%27): question mark, semicolon, newline. Maybe there's a difference in version of the console. I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: I also can't move the caret over it, but can select it. So to double check, you would say the output of `?;` is 1 byte, or still 0 like in your answer since the program doesn't add the extra character, VBA does?

Comment: Output is 0 bytes. You add the newline by pushing enter - that also executes the code. The code itself does utterly nothing.