# How does one calculate bytes for a solution to a Code Golf scenario?

Tags: discussion, support

I am new to Code Golf, and would like to start answering questions/scenarios posted on this Stack Exchange Site. I have seen many scenarios posted before, and have come up with solutions for said scenario, as well as seeing *how* a answer is submitted for a given scenario (i.e. the language name, followed by the byte size of your proposed solution, etc).

What is stopping me from submitting answers on these questions is that I am not sure how to calculate the bytes size of my solution. Do we only submit the byte size of the code we created, and discard the rest (like the main method declarations and imports from external libraries), or do we submit the byte size of the entire solution (i.e. Imports and all)?

Comment: The length of the entire code counts.  If you are looking for more details, we have a full FAQ on this: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-to-count-bytes-faq